# Set form fields based on default var value and on change

Tags: jquery

Ok so I am trying to have the script append data to a div based on the default var value initially set and also change when requested

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bettype = "Treble";
var data = '';
        (function(adddata){
if(bettype == "single")
            {
              data = '<div>Single Selected</div>';
              $('removethis').empty();
              $('#row').append(data);
            } else if(bettype == "double")
            {
              data = '<div>Double Selected</div>';
              $('removethis').empty();
              $('#row').append(data);
            } else if(bettype == "Treble")
            {
              data = '<div>Treble Selected</div>';
              $('removethis').empty();
              $('#row').append(data);
            }
});
$("#bettype").change(function(adddata){
             bettype = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
             });
});
```

It worked when I change the dropdown but since trying to add the default value and initial data added it doesnt work
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

it is about variable scope. do this modification (added parameter to your immediate function)

```
 (function(adddata){
if(bettype == "single")
            {
              data = '<div>Single Selected</div>';
              $('removethis').empty();
              $('#row').append(data);
            } else if(bettype == "double")
            {
              data = '<div>Double Selected</div>';
              $('removethis').empty();
              $('#row').append(data);
            } else if(bettype == "Treble")
            {
              data = '<div>Treble Selected</div>';
              $('removethis').empty();
              $('#row').append(data);
            }
}(bettype)); // <--- here is modification
```